# How to upload image to aws 3 with a specific name in form REACTJS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'd like to upload images to AWS s3 in a form that contains the name, description, and picture field.

After submitting the form, each item with its name, description, and images would be displayed in the table.

For now, I only know how to upload images to AWS s3 with the image its own name. I have deleted some code to leave only the relevant.

Also, if I want to hash the name of the item to avoid a duplicate name(item id is different, with auto-increment), then how do I get images from the AWS s3 bucket to the table in the corresponding place?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import S3 from 'aws-s3';
import { Form, Button, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

const config = {
    bucketName: process.env.REACT_APP_BUCKET_NAME,
    dirName: process.env.REACT_APP_DIR_NAME,
    region: process.env.REACT_APP_REGION,
    accessKeyId: process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
}
const S3Client = new S3(config);

export default class Home extends Component {
    state = {
        selectedFile: null
    };

    onFileChange = event => {
        this.setState({ selectedFile: event.target.files[0] });
    };

   changeItem = (key, value) => {
     const { newItem, items } = this.props.itemState;
     newItem[key] = value;
     this.props.updateNewItem(items, newItem);
   };

    upload(e){
        console.log(e.target.files[0]);
        S3Client.uploadFile(this.state.selectedFile, this.state.selectedFile.name)
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1> upload Item </h1>
                <Form onSubmit={() => this.upload()}>
                    <Col>
                        <label> 
                            Name:
                            <input type="text" value={newItem["item_name"]}   onChange={(e) =>
                              this.changeItem("item_name", e.target.value)
                      }/>
                        </label>
                    </Col>
                    <Col> 
                        <label> 
                            Description:
                            <input type="text" value={newItem["item_description"]}  onChange={(e) =>
                              this.changeItem("item_description", e.target.value) />
                        </label>
                    </Col>
                    <Col> 
                        <label>
                            Image: 
                            <input type="file" onChange={this.onFileChange}
                            />
                        </label>
                    </Col>
                    <Button type="submit">Add </Button>
                 </Form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of ideas:

1. generate a UUID for each uploaded image, store the objects in S3 with the object keys set to the UUID (rather than your hash + auto-incremented value**), write one or more items to DynamoDB containing the UUIDs and the original filename, description, associated with whatever user or entity they relate to
2. similar to above, but store the metadata (the original image's filename and description) as tags on the uploaded S3 object and store the objects under a folder whose prefix identifies the user or entity that uploaded them (to save having to use DynamoDB to correlate user/entity to images)

** auto-incrementing isn't a great design for a distributed environment.

Comment: thank you, and helped me to clean the thoughts